# How to set properly GridView?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

How to set **GridView** perfectly under **Toolbar**. I want the `margin` to be `"0dp"` on the all devices. How to do this?

I was tried set `marginTop` but on the devices with the large screen **GridView** cover the *Toolbar*. It looks different on individual devices.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="Application"/>


    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"></GridView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Oh, sorry for wrong tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a relative layout. 
Inside the relative layout, you place your toolbar and your GridView.

Inside the GridView, write this line :

```
android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
```

it will put the GridView below the toolbar.

Like this :

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:title="Application"/>


<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="8dp"></GridView>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

You have 2 options :

1) You can simply post this code inside your constraint layout and type the command you want (that concern the constraintlayout) in the RelativeLayout

2) Directly replace the ConstraintLayout with the RelativeLayout (I recommend you this method in this case, this is much easier to code)